# The console shows up a long object and I can't figure out what the error is whenever I make a post request to update a Mongoose database,

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have 3 Mongoose collection: Board, Thread and Reply. Each Reply belongs to 1 Thread and each Thread belongs to 1 Board.
When I want to add a new Reply to a Thread, I make a post request with form data including thread_id (from an existing Thread).

This code run well when I post to an existing thread_id, but when I tried to make a post request with an unavailable thread_id, the console showed a lot of stuffs and I can't figure out what the error was. (expected output: "Thread not found").

Please help me. I'm new to this and really want to receive comments from everyone!

My problem is at the route `/api/replies/:board`. If there's no `updateThread`, the console doesn't show "Thread not found" as I expected but a long object like this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGyJo.png) (I scrolled to the top but it seemed that the console didn't have enough space to show the full error)

```
'use strict';

const BoardModel = require('../models').Board;
const ThreadModel = require('../models').Thread;
const ReplyModel = require('../models').Reply;

module.exports = function (app) {
  
  app.route('/api/threads/:board').post(async (req, res) => {
    const { text, delete_password } = req.body;
    let { board } = req.body;
    if (!board) {
      board = req.params.board;
    }
    
    //Add new Thread
    const newThread = new ThreadModel({
      text: text,
      reported: false,
      delete_password: delete_password,
      replies: [],
    })
    let saveThread = await newThread.save();
    console.log("New thread added:");
    console.log(newThread.text);

    //Add new Board
    const oldBoard = await BoardModel.findOne({ name: board }).exec();
    if (!oldBoard) {
      const newBoard = new BoardModel({
        name: board,
        threads: [newThread],
      })
      let saveBoard = await newBoard.save();
      console.log("New thread added to this new board:");
      console.log(newBoard.name);
      res.json(saveBoard)
    } else {
      oldBoard.threads.push(newThread);
      let saveBoard = await oldBoard.save()
      console.log("New thread added to the existing board:");
      console.log(oldBoard.name);
      res.json(saveBoard);
    }
  });
    
  app.route('/api/replies/:board').post(async (req, res) => {
    const { text, delete_password, thread_id } = req.body;
    let { board } = req.body;
    if (!board) {
      board = req.params.board;
    }
   
    const updateThread = await ThreadModel.findById(thread_id).exec();
    if (!updateThread) {
      console.log("Thread not found");   
      res.send("Thread not found");
    }
    //Add new Reply
    const newReply = new ReplyModel({
      text: text,
      delete_password: delete_password,
      reported: false,
    })
    let saveReply = await newReply.save();
    console.log("New reply added:");
    console.log(newReply.text);

    //Update Thread
    updateThread.replies.push(saveReply);
    let saveThread = await updateThread.save();
    console.log('New reply added to this thread:');
    console.log(updateThread.text);

    res.json(saveReply);
  });

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By chaining `exec()` onto your Model methods it provides a fuller stack trace which is why you get the long error message. I think what might help you is by using a `try/catch` block to catch the error if any then decide what to do with it or use an early return statement to return the response. Update your code like so:

```js
try{ //< Use of try/catch
   const updateThread = await ThreadModel.findById(thread_id);
    if (!updateThread) {
      console.log("Thread not found");   
      return res.send("Thread not found"); //< Early return
    }
    //Add new Reply
    const newReply = new ReplyModel({
      text: text,
      delete_password: delete_password,
      reported: false,
    })
    let saveReply = await newReply.save();
    console.log("New reply added:");
    console.log(newReply.text); //< Did you mean saveReply.text here?

    //Update Thread
    updateThread.replies.push(saveReply);
    let saveThread = await updateThread.save();
    console.log('New reply added to this thread:');
    console.log(updateThread.text); //< Did you mean saveThread.text here?


    res.json(saveReply);
}catch(err){
   console.log(err);
   res.status(500).json({
      message: 'An error occurred on the server'
   });
}
```

Comment: Oh now I can see the error. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.